# Is there a portable version of namedtuple which doesn't allow indexing?

Tags: python

namedtuple is a great choice for creating immutable record classes in Python, as it eliminates boilerplate. However, a namedtuple still supports positional indexing `x[0]`. Is there a way to define something like a namedtuple in Python 2 and Python 3, but without positional indexing?

Comment: How about [dataclasses](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html)?

Comment: It's a good idea, but Python 3.7 only. Let's refine the question to require portability. Maybe dataclasses compat library supports Python 2 as well?

Comment: @EdwardZ.Yang: there is a backport, and there is `attrs`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are talking about [dataclasses](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/dataclasses.html):

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass(frozen=True)
class Foo:
    bar: str
    baz: str

Foo('spam', 'ham')[0]  # TypeError
```

Dataclasses are designed to eliminate boilerplate when building simple classes to hold data. They are not a subclass of `tuple`, the way `namedtuple` classes *are*.

Note that while the `dataclasses` library is new in Python 3.7, there is also a [backport](https://pypi.org/project/dataclasses/) that works on 3.6. For earlier Python versions [or more complex requirements](https://www.attrs.org/en/stable/why.html#data-classes), use the [`attrs` project](https://pypi.org/project/attrs/), which inspired `dataclasses`.